# Centrar carrusel de imagenes bootstrap

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap, bootstrap-carousel

Estoy haciendo un carrusel en bootstrap pero al definir:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
```

Con el 12 si aparece centrado en la pantalla, pero si quiero hacerlo mas pequeño por ejemplo:

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
```

Con el 8 sale mas pegado del lado derecho de la pantalla. Saben como puedo centrarlo?

Les agradeceria mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dependiendo de la version de Bootstrap que utilices, puedes intentar lo siguiente:

```
<!-- Bootstrap v3 -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2"></div>
</div>

<!-- Bootstrap v4 -->
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-sm-8"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, lo resolví con el de Bootstrap v3. de verdad muchas gracias.